# Python Dash - Basic Authentication with multiple usernames filtering database based on user input in username

Tags: python, sql, authentication, plotly-dash

I have an SQL database that stores all my data. I have a column there called “client_name” where I have client1, client2, etc.

I have created a basic dash authentication where as soon as my dash application loads, it asks the user for a username and password.

How can I make it work that if the user inputs “client1” as username, the app will automatically filter my SQL database to only read rows that belong to client1 and thus all visuals will display client1’s data?

Sample code

```
# User dictionary
USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS = {
     'client1': 'client1'
    , 'client2': 'client2'
}

# Basic authentication
auth = dash_auth.BasicAuth(
    app,
    USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS
)


# Connect and read data from SQL server
odbc_params = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER=tcp:{server};PORT=1433;DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'
connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={odbc_params}'
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test]"  # database with all client data
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
engine.dispose()
```

So I want the “df” to read the filtered dataframe based on wether “client1” or “client2” was used to log in.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have a column in df which is named "client" or something alike. You need to get the name of the logged in user, and then filter the df for it:

```
username = auth.get_username()
df_filtered_for_client = df[df["client"].isin([username])
```

Comment: When I run the above code, i am getting: AttributeError: 'BasicAuth' object has no attribute 'get_username'